# How use a overridden toString() method in java

Tags: java, overriding, tostring

I have to override the toString() method and I have done so as below

```
public String toString() {
     String str = "The zoo is capable of keeping " + park.length + "animals\nThe following is the list of animals currently in the zoo.";
        for(int i = 0; i < park.length; i++)
            str += '\n' + "cage " + i + " status: " + park[i];

        return str;
}
```

and created another method to print this

```
public void print() {
    System.out.println(park.toString());
}
```

Somehow when I use the print method in my main method, the following comes up

```
[LAnimal;@3a67ad79
```

Now, someone suggested to me that I might actually be using the default toString() method and hence bringing the actual address memory.

What do you guys reckon the problem is?

Comment: We need more data. In what class is `toString()` implemented in? What is `park` in `print`? What is `LAnimal`?

Comment: @whoAmI is right, you must did some mistake over there.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot override `toString` for array, use [`Arrays#toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) instead.

Answer (score 2):

From the use of `park.length` and the application output it appears that `park` is an array of type `Animal`. *Therefore*

```
System.out.println(park.toString());
```

should be

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(park));
```

(since `Arrays` don't override the `Object#toString` method)

Answer (score 0):

you must add @Override

```
@Override public String toString() {
     String str = "The zoo is capable of keeping " + park.length + "animals\nThe following   is     the list of animals currently in the zoo.";
        for(int i = 0; i < park.length; i++)
            str += '\n' + "cage " + i + " status: " + park[i];

    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are printing `park[i]` within you `toString()` method

```
str += '\n' + "cage " + i + " status: " + park[i];

                                          ^
                                          |_________ Here you are printing the Object
```